# Outputting multi level XML from SQL query result

Tags: xml, sql-server-2012

I am trying to convert a SQL Server 2012 query result to a formatted XML result.
I normally do this using Visual Basic looping through a recordset and forming it.

The query is:

```
SELECT top 3
    Plant_Devices.DeviceNumber, Plant_Devices.DeviceName, 
    SYS_Templates.TemplateTag, Plant_Alarms_Groups.GroupTag
FROM
    Plant_Devices 
INNER JOIN 
    SYS_Templates ON Plant_Devices.SYS_Templates_CID = SYS_Templates.CID 
INNER JOIN 
    Plant_Alarms_Groups ON Plant_Devices.Plant_Alarms_Groups_CID = Plant_Alarms_Groups.CID 
                        AND Plant_Devices.Plant_Alarms_Groups_CID = Plant_Alarms_Groups.CID
```

The results are:

```
DeviceNumber    DeviceName  TemplateTag GroupTag
1   Stucco & Dry Add. D/C Fan   D_Motor_Standard    WM1_StuccoSys
10  Kiln Drive  D_Drive_Standard    WM1_KilnSys
118 HRA Feeder Agitator #1  D_Motor_Standard    WM1_DryAdditives
```

The needed XML output is:

```
<Tags>
   <Tag name="1" path="" type="UDT_INST">
      <Property name="Documentation" type="String">Stucco &amp; Dry Add. D/C Fan</Property>
      <Property name="DataType">2</Property>
      <Property name="UDTParentType">D_Motor_Standard</Property>
      <Parameters>
         <Property name="AlarmGroup" type="String">WM1_StuccoSys</Property>
         <Property name="DisplayName" type="String">1</Property>
         <Property name="ID" type="String">1</Property>
          </Parameters>
       </Tag>
       <Tag name="10" path="" type="UDT_INST">
          <Property name="Documentation" type="String">Kiln Drive</Property>
          <Property name="DataType">2</Property>
          <Property name="UDTParentType">D_Drive_Standard</Property>
          <Parameters>
             <Property name="AlarmGroup" type="String">WM1_KilnSys</Property>
             <Property name="DisplayName" type="String">10</Property>
             <Property name="ID" type="String">10</Property>
          </Parameters>
       <Tag name="118" path="" type="UDT_INST">
          <Property name="Documentation" type="String">HRA Feeder Agitator     #1</Property>
          <Property name="DataType">2</Property>
          <Property name="UDTParentType">D_Motor_Standard</Property>
          <Parameters>
             <Property name="AlarmGroup" type="String">WM1_DryAdditives</Property>
             <Property name="DisplayName" type="String">118</Property>
             <Property name="ID" type="String">118</Property>
          </Parameters>
       </Tag>
    </Tag>
</Tags>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You might find that you need to be more specific upon how exactly you are wanting to achieve your end results. Are you wanting to use VB Script again? Or are you looking to find another solution? I really cannot see a question in here, it looks more like a do this for me.

Comment: I've been trying to use the xml generator inside SQL server to output the required XML. But I can't seem to get the second and third level branches to output.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are looking for but I would use XML Linq like this

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt.Columns.Add("DeviceNumber", GetType(Integer))
        dt.Columns.Add("DeviceName", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("TemplateTag", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("GroupTag", GetType(String))

        dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {1, "Stucco & Dry Add. D/C Fan", "D_Motor_Standard", "WM1_StuccoSys"})
        dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {10, "Kiln Drive", "D_Drive_Standard", "WM1_KilnSys"})
        dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {118, "HRA Feeder Agitator #1", "D_Motor_Standard", "WM1_DryAdditives"})

        Dim tags As New XElement("Tags")

        For Each row As DataRow In dt.AsEnumerable
            Dim deviceNumber As Integer = row("DeviceNumber")
            Dim deviceName As String = row("DeviceName")
            Dim templateTag As String = row("TemplateTag")
            Dim groupTag As String = row("GroupTag")

            Dim tag As XElement = New XElement("Tag", New Object() {New XAttribute("name", deviceNumber), New XAttribute("path", ""), New XAttribute("type", "UDT_INST")})
            tags.Add(tag)


            Dim properties As List(Of XElement) = New List(Of XElement)({ _
                New XElement("Property", New Object() {New XAttribute("name", "Documentation"), New XAttribute("type", "String"), deviceName}), _
                New XElement("Property", New Object() {New XAttribute("name", "DataType"), 2}), _
                New XElement("Property", New Object() {New XAttribute("name", "UDTParentType"), templateTag}) _
            })
            tag.Add(properties)

            properties = New List(Of XElement)({ _
                New XElement("Property", New Object() {New XAttribute("name", "AlarmGroup"), New XAttribute("type", "String"), groupTag}), _
                New XElement("Property", New Object() {New XAttribute("name", "DisplayName"), New XAttribute("type", "String"), deviceNumber}), _
                New XElement("Property", New Object() {New XAttribute("name", "ID"), New XAttribute("type", "String"), deviceNumber}) _
            })

            Dim parameters As XElement = New XElement("Parameters", properties)
            tag.Add(parameters)
        Next
    End Sub

End Module
​
```

Comment: Thanks, I am familiar with doing this inside of Visual Basic, what I am trying to do is generate this inside of SQL Server using a query and the FOR XML options.

Comment: You can query SQL server from Visual Basic and get the datatable.  Not sure if custom xml can be achieved in SQL Server.